# Solving ODE with Fourier Transform: $u(x) - u''(x) = x^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-transform

Solve:

$$u(x) - u''(x) = x^2$$

You can use: 
$$
\mathcal{F} \{ e^{-a|x|} \} = \frac{2a}{a^2 + s^2}
$$

I am new to Fourier transforms. I understand that limits have to be used but don't know how to start. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! What have you tried for the solution?

Comment: @rafa11111 I am new to Fourier transforms. I understand that limits have to be used but don't know how to start. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @Beth: insert that comment in the question.

Comment: You need to take the Fourier transform of both members.

Answer (score 2):

You probably are to use that
$$
x^2=\left.\frac{\partial^2}{\partial a^2}e^{-a|x|}\right|_{a=0}
$$
and consider first the solution of 
$$
u_a(x)-u_a''(x)=e^{-a|x|}
$$
to then compute
$$
u=\left.\frac{\partial^2}{\partial a^2}u_a(x)\right|_{a=0}.
$$

---

Check against the solution you get via undetermined coefficients, $u_p=ax^2+bx+c$.